# What is the timestamp in a c++ exe (IDL to TLB file using MIDL)

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I was analyzing a file written in Microsoft Visual C++  2012 ,and found a string i.e "Created by MIDL version 7.00.0555 at Sat Sep 20 23:13:16 2014" ,I understand that this is there because a MIDL compiler was used.The version number I understand.
My question is :What does the date signify?

Comment: Maybe when the file was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reverse engineer, I wouldn't trust any "build date" type literal strings that you would find in the disassembly.

What you want is the TimeDateStamp from EXE header (PE Header).   If you go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx you can see a good guide on what information is located in this header.  Of interest to you is this line under Table 2:

```
DWORD TimeDateStamp
The time that the linker (or compiler for an OBJ file) produced this file. This field holds the number of seconds since December 31st, 1969, at 4:00 P.M.
```

A few years ago I had a need to get the TimeDateStamp only, so I repurposed this fast (and very hackish) C++ that I saw somewhere online (at least, I think I borrowed it -- I could very well have written it from scratch ..it's been too long!)   Of course, this function is intended to be called from WITHIN the executable being checked...but, you get the idea:

```
unsigned int GetExecutableTimestamp()
{
    unsigned int BaseAddress = (unsigned int)GetModuleHandle(0);
    unsigned int dwPos = *(unsigned int*)(BaseAddress+0x3C);
    unsigned int Timestamp = *(unsigned int*)(BaseAddress+dwPos+0x8);
    return Timestamp;
}
```

Comment: I guess that even `TimeDateStamp` can be spoofed/modified?

Comment: Well, yea, it's possible to modify anything if you really wish to do so.  But, at least with TimeDateStamp it would be an "active" hack/spoof/modification.

In general, the compiler is the least likely to be producing modified values without active hacks/spoofs.  While, other libraries/software might have settings and/or other UI values that could be used to create special dates/times, etc.

Also, the string literals in the disassembly might be created a few seconds before or after the actual linker/compiler produced the file.

You raise a valid point; however, I think TDS is the best choice.

Comment: I should also mention that the other inherit benefit to using "TimeDateStamp" is that it's always in the same place :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the date when the `.exe` was created.

Comment: Thankyou ,but I have 3 exe's with different sizes which have this same time stamp,then how can 3 exe have the same time of compiling?

Comment: If it was a projectmap it could be that they've been built at the same time.